# Convert JSON to HTML using an APEX class

Tags: apex, json, html

Want to create a class that can convert any json to HTML in a tabular form. Just like http://any-json2html.lkatney.com/. We have the source code in javascript as well (https://github.com/lkatney/ANY-JSON2HTML/blob/master/scripts/json.htmTable.js). I'm not sure how we can proceed.
Here is the piece of code that i have written taking the given source code as reference.

```
public class JsonToHTML {
    public static void createTableView(){
        Map<String, Object> parsedJson = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped('{"Name":"S","children":[{"title":"D"}]}');
        System.debug(parsedJson);
        Boolean found =false;
        Boolean enableHeader = true;
        Boolean firstTableFound = false;
        String str = '';
        String theme = 'lightPro';
        Integer row = 0;
        Integer count = 0;
        if(firstTableFound){ //defined false on line 7 so else will be executed
            str += '<div class="scrollable-table"><table class="' + theme + '">';  // As per the DOM it set table
         }else{
            str += '<table class="' + theme + '">'; // adding the theme to table
            found = true;
            firstTableFound = true;
         }
         str += '<tbody>';   // after table  As per the DOM it set body
        for(String key : parsedJson.keySet()){
            Object value = parsedJson.get(key);
            System.debug(key);
            System.debug(value);
            row++;
            count++;
             str += (math.mod(row,2) == 0) ? '<tr class="alt">' : '<tr>'; 
              if (enableHeader) {
                str += '<th scope="row">' + count + '</th>'; 
             }
             str += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
             str += '</tr>';
             str += '</tbody>';
              str += '</table>';
        }
        System.debug(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish at the end of the day (sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/))?  Creating HTML code via Apex could probably be avoided if you try using something like [`lightning-datatable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) or something similar.  There's lot of options across the different technologies Salesforce offers (Visualforce pages, Aura components, Lightning Web Components, etc) that should avoid producing HTML code within Apex itself

Comment: @BrianMiller That makes sense but my requirement is to collect an json response and show it in a table format to an end user. * i cant use lightning components here

Comment: You could "separate the concerns" by moving the HTML generation part out to Visualforce or to an LWC and so benefit from the templating features of either.